# How to compare without getting negative value when char is a space

Tags: java, arrays, char

Beginner here, We were assigned an assignment to find common consonants in two different strings. This code works perfectly if there is no space in the input but in this assignment we are taking inputs from our user and they are first and last names. If there is no space I get correct value of common characters but when there is a space in between first and last names it will give me an index out of bounds error because the space makes it a negative number. Any help would be nice thank you.

```
public static int commonCharacters(String string1, String string2) {
        final int alphabetLength = 26;
        int count = 0;

        int[] counting1 = new int[alphabetLength];
        int[] counting2 = new int[alphabetLength];

        Arrays.fill(counting1, 0);
        Arrays.fill(counting2, 0);

        for (char c : string1.toCharArray()) {
            c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
            counting1[c - 'a']++;
             }
        for (char c :  string2.toCharArray()) {
            c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
            counting2[c - 'a']++;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < alphabetLength; i++) {
                System.out.printf(String.valueOf(counting1[i]),counting2[i]);

                count += Math.min(counting1[i], counting2[i]);

        }
        return count == 0 ? 1 :count;


    }
}
```

Comment: `if (c >= 'a') ...`

Comment: and, presumably, `c <= 'z'`.

Comment: ```if((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'))``` you can use a condition to check if the character is a valid alphabet and ignore the consonants in the end when you count for common characters..

Comment: NB `Arrays.fill(counting1, 0);` is redundant, as Java arrays are initialized to zero already.

Comment: Can I see your main method (maybe something to do with your input)?

Answer (score 0):

you can trim space at the end of string `string1 = string1.trim();`

Answer (score 0):

Here is some changes to your code. You just need if statement to check if the character is an alphabet. You do not need `Arrays.fill` because in Java array values are initialized to zero.

You wrote the assignment is about calculating consonants but your code calculates all common alphabets.

```
public static int commonCharacters(String string1, String string2) {
    final int alphabetLength = 26;
    int count = 0;

    string1 = string1.toLowerCase();
    string2 = string2.toLowerCase();
    int[] counting1 = new int[alphabetLength];
    int[] counting2 = new int[alphabetLength];

    for (char c : string1.toCharArray()) {
        if (c < 'a' || c > 'z') {
            continue;
        }
        counting1[c - 'a']++;
    }
    for (char c :  string2.toCharArray()) {
        if (c < 'a' || c > 'z') {
            continue;
        }
        counting2[c - 'a']++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < alphabetLength; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%c %d %d%n", 'a' + i, counting1[i], counting2[i]);
        count += Math.min(counting1[i], counting2[i]);
    }
    return count;
}
```